# How Can I Make My Google Firebase-Hosted Static Site Faster?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting a static website generated by Hugo on Google Firebase. I know Firebase simplifies a lot of things from Google Cloud via its console and default settings. However, I'm hoping to make my site faster, and I was wondering if there was any settings I could change on the larger Google Cloud platform such as increasing the number of places the site deploys from, or using an SSD, or a faster virtual machine etc.

This is for a static website generated by Hugo being hosted on Google Firebase and with a CDN via CloudFlare. I've done plenty of optimization via the typical website optimization stuff, but I was wondering if there was anything I could do on Google Cloud Platform to increase the reach of my site and its speed etc.

Comment: When you say "on Google Firebase", do you mean you're deploying static content to Firebase Hosting?  That already has a CDN, so I don't understand why you need another one.

Comment: Well, since I'm on the pay-as-you-go plan, I'm trying to reduce the costs and also beef up security by having it dispersed through CloudFlare's network. For example, Firebase has no rate limiting and doesn't have brotli compression.

Comment: Though I notice you work for the Firebase team, so you definitely know far better than me!! Would appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting doesn't have any configurations that tune its runtime behavior, in terms of performance.  The only configurations it has are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config).